# Location of windows service icon

Tags: windows, icons

### Question

I would like to use the icon that is used for the MMC when you go to `Start -> Run -> services.msc`.

It's the two little gears icon that I'm after.

### Furthermore

Is every icon Windows uses for the system applications/services in one location or are they all scattered around?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The gears icon is taken from this file:

```
%windir%\system32\filemgmt.dll,0
```

For the other question, most of the icons are in `imageres.dll`, `shell32.dll` and some programs include their own icons inside the DLL/EXE.